# Enumerate deja de comparar correctamente cuando la ingreso en una función def

Tags: python-3.x, funciones, comparaciones

tengo el siguiente problema.
Estoy creando un juego de adivina el número donde el jugador debe adivinar aproximando sus aciertos por número y posición en un número de 4 dígitos.
Por cada intento el programa devuelve cantidad de aciertos en número y posición y en número pero no en posición.
Este problema ya lo tengo resuelto, utilicé la función ENUMERATE y comparé valores y posiciones.
PROBLEMA: cuando quiero meter todo en una función DEF el comparador empieza a funcionar mal, y me devuelve cualquier cosa.

Gracias!

```
def adivinarNumero():
while pensador:
    bien = 0
    regular = 0
    adiv= input()
    adivinador= list(adiv)
    for pIndex, pVal in enumerate(adivinador):
        for aIndex, aVal in enumerate(pensador):
            if pVal==aVal and pIndex==aIndex:
                bien = bien + 1
            elif pVal==aVal and pIndex != aIndex:
                regular = regular + 1           

    if adivinador != pensador:
        print (str(bien) + ' están BIEN y ' + str(regular) +' están REGULAR')
        time.sleep(2)
        print('Seguí intentando')

    if adivinador == pensador:
        break
print ('GANASTE!')
```

Comment: Bienvenido Gerardo Grana a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: ¿De dónde sale `pensador`? ¿Que significa que retorna "cualquier cosa"?

Answer (score 0):

**pensador** es un **número aleatorio** realizado la la función **random.randint**

El resultado de la adivinanza es siempre una sumatoria de números BIEN y números REGULAR.

BIEN= acierto en número y posición.

REGULAR= es número correcto y posición incorrecta.

El programa devuelve algo como ... están BIEN y ... están REGULAR.

Cuando ingreso el bloque **while** en un **def** el conteo de BIEN y REGULAR retorna valores incorrectos (con acierto exactos de los 4 dígitos puede indicar 0 BIEN y 1 REGULAR) o ilógicos (ej: 1 BIEN y 6 REGULAR).